# Partially dropping data when fetching data over internet

Tags: java, android, http

I encountered this "bug" (quoting because I'm not sure if it's just me missing something really simple and obvious) when helping my GF code some simple android GUI.

This app fetches some data over the internet and displays charts that visualize the data.

I have some code like this:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            stream = conn.getInputStream();

            return readStream(stream, conn.getContentLength());
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public String readStream(InputStream stream, int bufferLength) throws IOException {
        char[] buffer = new char[bufferLength];
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "ascii"));
        reader.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

I use the above code as a base class and implement `onPostExecute` in private classes inside other classes.

The problem is, when I get the result in `onPostExecute`, the string is not complete. Note: I wrote the server, so I can guarantee that the content length is correct.

The first couple hundred characters are correct, but at some point, I start to see unknown characters. I tried using a byte array to read the raw stream and saw the unknown characters are just 0s. So the stream looks like: [... 54 52 53 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...]. Basically, correct bytes followed by all zeros.

I wonder why the stream is chopped off, and how to make it read the whole response correctly. Note: this "bug" happens on some phones very consistently and not so consistently on others.

Some more details about the data, it's pure text, comma or space separated lines, lines separated by \n (as I said above I wrote the server. I used to use commas, changed it to spaces just to test whether it's the problem). The data size is about 2000 bytes, not large at all I would assume.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: try logging your response and show us the logs

Comment: Just checking: do you remember to flush() the OutputStream on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why the stream is chopped off, and how to make it read the
>   whole response correctly.

When you read from an `InputStream` that comes from the network, not all the bytes could be all available at the same time.

```
public String readStream(InputStream stream, int bufferLength) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```